# ISChanged and IsNew in Process Builder

Tags: formula, process-builder, process

Been banging my head on getting IsChanged and IsNew to work in Process Builder. I'm looking for the first two statements to be true and then check to ensure "Request for Portal User" is true but only fires if it's new value.

```
AND(
(($Setup.Hierarchy_Settings__c.Skip_Process_Builder__c == False), 
 ([Contact].RecordType.DeveloperName == $Label.Contact_Record_Type))  
    OR(
    AND(
        ISNEW(),
        NOT(
            ISBLANK(
                TEXT([Contact].Request_Portal_User_Account__c == True)
                )
            )
        ),

    AND(
        ISCHANGED([Contact].Request_Portal_User_Account__c == True),
        NOT(
            ISBLANK(
                TEXT([Contact].Request_Portal_User_Account__c == True))
                )
            )
        )
)
```

Comment: Text function always expect a number,string, date, datetime value but you are returning boolean. Are you able to save above? What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This formula snippet

```
        ISBLANK(
            TEXT([Contact].Request_Portal_User_Account__c == True)
            )
```

is never going to evaluate to `true`. The text value of that Boolean expression would always be a non-blank string (`"True"` or `"False"`), if this even compiles.

Remember that the `NOT()` function takes a Boolean, and Checkbox fields are Booleans. You can pass one to the `NOT()` function directly.

If we make those substitutions, remove some of your extra parentheses, and add a comma (I don't believe your formula as written will compile), you come out with

```
AND(
    NOT($Setup.Hierarchy_Settings__c.Skip_Process_Builder__c), 
    [Contact].RecordType.DeveloperName == $Label.Contact_Record_Type,  
    OR(
        AND(
            ISNEW(),
            NOT([Contact].Request_Portal_User_Account__c)
        ),
        AND(
            ISCHANGED([Contact].Request_Portal_User_Account__c),
            NOT([Contact].Request_Portal_User_Account__c)
        )
    )
)
```

That's going to be true if the first two conditions are true, and `Request_Portal_User_Account__c` is `false` on a new record or is changed to `false` on an existing record.

Comment: `NOT($Setup.Hierarchy_Settings__c.Skip_Process_Builder__c)`?

Comment: Thank you very much, yes my condition wasn't working but all the error message said was "missing a ')'" so I didn't have much to go off of.  Thanks again!!